# 英語が残っている: questions with no upvoted or accepted answers

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

「未回答」ー「私のタグ」の画面右側に英語が残っている（以下）。
「新着」、「票」も同様に英語が残っている。
「未回答」のみ翻訳されている。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用翻訳：

> 未回答やベストアンサーなし質問